# Transforming xml and preserving Doctype

Tags: xml, xslt

I know, this has been asked before, but still ...

Just keep in mind that I'm new to xslt so have patience please :-)

I have multiple files with doctype containing lots of different entities looking like this:

```
<!ENTITY I-042-A-001 SYSTEM 'I-042-A-001.CGM' NDATA cgm>.
```

There's no way of telling the content of each doctype in each document so I have to get a hold of these somehow, since this is crucial in my transformed document.

As I understand it, there's no way of doing this with XSLT 1.0, and no easy way of doing this with XSLT 2.0. So how can it be done?

Now comes the part where people will tell me in more than a thousand ways that I really should reconcider ;-)
I will use Java or Python to parse and transform. Why not just deal with it as two separate parts and then combine the results? Getting the doctype as an ordinary string should be easy, and doing for instance an identity transform should also be easy. Writing both parts to a file should go ok. So why go about this other ways?

Comment: http://andrewjwelch.com/lexev/ allows preserving the doctype, it is implemented in Java.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out!